# Vue HTTP request without Vue Resources & Axios

Tags: vue.js, httprequest

Is it possible to make http request without using Vue Resources & Axios in Vue? The reason why I am asking this questions is that "In my exam, they don't allow Axios and vue resources"? Could you recommend any other options to make http request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the xmlhttprequest or fetch api in almost any browser.
This is part of JS which Vue is built upon.

xmlhttprequest:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

fetch:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 1):

You could try this simple HTTP JavaScript class:
https://github.com/jakecyr/Slim-Http-JavaScript-Object

It's worked well for me in the past with Vue.js